# Many buttons, many problems (crash)

Tags: android, android-button

I made 2 buttons in android activity linked with separate classes, each class has 4 to 5 buttons and each is coded for sending a message to a particular person. But when I run it on my device, the app crashes.

This is my code:

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone-number));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me why the app crashes?

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Button z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        z.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String messageToSend = "Come Out Bro....";
                 String fnumber = "03339579504";    
                 SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(fnumber, null, messageToSend, null,null);


            }
        });

        Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View y) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String messageSend = "Come Out Bro....";
                 String snumber = "03339023418";    
                 SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(snumber, null, messageSend, null,null);

            }
        });


        Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt4);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View u) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ToSend = "Come Out Bro....";
             String anumber = "03443444720";    
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(anumber, null, ToSend, null,null);



        }
    });

    Button v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt5);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String kmessageToSend = "Come Out Bro....";
             String knumber = "03139644916";    
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(knumber, null, kmessageToSend, null,null);     

        }

    });

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt6);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String almessageToSend = "Come Out Bro....";
             String alnumber = "03451923255";   
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(alnumber, null, almessageToSend, null,null);       



        }
    });

    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt3);
    n.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View p) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String zamessageToSend = "Come Out Bro....";
             String zanumber = "03015932300";   
             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(zanumber, null, zamessageToSend, null,null);       



        }
    });
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you post the log and also the entire code in a class along with the contents in one of the layout.

Comment: `telephone-number`... are you really calculating `telephone` minus `number`?

Comment: @Raza - please take some time to [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You are not really using the site as well as you could. You're probably not going to get quality answers, and its going to effect your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permission in Manifest?

Add this to make a phone calls and send messages -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

If you have more buttons performing such actions then you have to first add permissions in Manifest.